# How to set max user in jitsi room

Tags: jitsi

I want to change the setting of max user limit of jitsi in one room, cause I saw there was `notifyMaxUsersLimitReached` in `UI.js`, so where should I set this value? In jicofo or videobridge? is it there:  https://github.com/jitsi/jicofo/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jitsi/jicofo/JitsiMeetGlobalConfig.java#L60
or other place?

Answer (score 0):

This value could be specified in the option `org.jitsi.jicofo.MAX_SSRC_PER_USER`

It could be set in /etc/jitsi/jicofo/config, in the variable `JAVA_SYS_PROPS`, something like :

> JAVA_SYS_PROPS="-Dorg.jitsi.jicofo.MAX_SSRC_PER_USER=100 ...."

Comment: is it possible to modify it in the sip-communicator.properties of jicofo?